# How do I change this cultural values via powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, regional-settings

So I'm making a script to change system language, culture and all that stuff. The concept is to make everything regarding system language to English US but make Russian remain as an **input method** option, and time format will remain European like too.

```
    $culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = 'dd-MM-yyyy'
    $culture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = 'dddd, d MMMM yyyy'
    $culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = 'H:mm'
    $culture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = 'H:mm:ss'
    $culture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek = 'Monday'
    Set-Culture en-US
    Set-Culture $culture
    Set-WinSystemLocale -SystemLocale en-US
    Set-WinUILanguageOverride -Language en-US
    Set-WinUserLanguageList ru-RU, en-US -Force
    Set-WinHomeLocation -GeoId 203
```

As you can see there are settings that change localization to English but some Russian are remain like `WinHomeLocation` or `WinUserLanguageSettings` list.

[image: The subject]

After applying if I go to the Welcome Screen Settings you can see there is a confusion. Location must be "Russia" for any user, format - EN US and input language by default as EN US.
What did I miss there?

Comment: I think you may need to create an xml and feed that to `intl.cpl` so you'll be able to also set the checkmarks under `Copy your current settings to:`. There's a blog about it [here](https://pontuswendt.blog/2019/04/17/changing-regionalsettings-for-all-countries-just-a-simple-powershell-script/)

Comment: @Theo You mean there is no native cmdlet support for this functionality in PowerShell?

Comment: Well.. at least not that I know of..